# d3.json call always gets null data

Tags: json, d3.js

If I make this call to the server from a browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/items/number/all.json
```

Or from curl:

```
curl -G http://localhost:8080/api/items/number/all.json
```

I get back the following json:

```
{
  "language": null,
  "number": 10,
  "queryId": 0,
  "from": null,
  "to": null,
  "percentage": 33,
  "dataInfoSet": null
}
```

However when I use `d3.json` call:

```
d3.json("http://localhost:8080/api/items/number/all.json", function(jsondata) {
  console.log(jsondata);
});
```

The output from `console.log` is `null`.

If instead the http call, I save the json in a file (fileWithData.json) and do:

```
d3.json("fileWithData.json", function(jsondata) {
  console.log(jsondata);
});
```

Everything works as expected. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Solved with the help of d3-js Goole group. The problem was that the page loading the json was not being served from localhost:8080, thus, there were cross domain restrictions.

Comment: I have this problem, but I am on port 8080. Very strange : (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with the help of d3-js Goole group. 
The problem was that the page loading the json was not being served from localhost:8080, thus, there were cross domain restrictions. I just deployed the file within the same application.
In case cross domain calls have to be made, the group suggested the use of jasonp and specially and CORS (
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/
)