# d3.js and geojson map throws error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to make a map with d3.js and geojson containing data about Denmark.

I have searched for hours now to find the problem. My code:

```
<div class="map"></div>
                        <script>
                            var canvas = d3.select(".map").append("svg")
                              .attr("width", 700)
                              .attr("height", 700)

                            d3.json("http://karsten-tietje.dk/bolig/dk.json",     
                            function (data){

                                var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
                                   .data(data.features)
                                   .enter()
                                   .append("g")

                                var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
                                var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

                                var areas = group.append("path")
                                    .attr("d", path)
                                    .attr("class","area")
                                    .attr("fill","steelblue")
                             });


                        </script>
```

The console show this:`data is null` for `.data(data.features)`

I can't figure out what is missing or wrong - any suggestions?

I'm using wordpress on a localhost if that matters.

Comment: The URL to the data you have in your code gives me a 404.

Comment: Sorry try this: http://karsten-tietje.dk/bolig/dk.geojson

Comment: Did you verify that the data is loaded correctly?

Comment: I did suppose that the data wasn't loaded at all because of the error in console. How can I check that?

Comment: You can use `d3.json(url, function(error, data) { ... });` and inspect `error`.

Comment: As far as i can see the json gets loaded correctly on my live site. You can check it at www.karsten-tietje.dk/bolig. But i still get `is null` error.

Comment: I'm getting an advertisment for a webhoster at that address.

Comment: www.karsten-tietje.dk/bolig - works perfectly in my browser.

Comment: Oh right -- I didn't expect there to be so much other stuff. The arguments to your callback for `d3.json` are the wrong way round.

Comment: This probably the most annoying thing I have researched in recent months and such a simple mistake. This reminds of my early days in programming then missing curly brackets screwed a thousand lines of code. Thank you very much, this was indeed the mistake! If you're write this as an answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code on your website (not in the code you've posted here), the arguments to the callback to `d3.json` are the wrong way round, i.e.

```
d3.json(url, function(data, error) { ... });
```

instead of

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) { ... });
```

as they should be.

Answer (score 1):

You may be failing on the json request due to cross-domain issues that pop up when you are on localhost. Example question : [d3.json call always gets null data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558719/d3-json-call-always-gets-null-data) .

You may need to host the data locally in order to test.

Comment: Already tried that without success. Also tried running it on a live site (www.karsten-tietje.dk/bolig). No luck.